# Powershell plink telnet command output into var

Tags: powershell, ssh, scripting, telnet, plink

I'm trying to write a script (based on some internet examples) for some telnet/ssh command execution, using powershell and plink. But the main feature, which I'd like to implement - is to catch this command's output into the variable or a text file. How can I intercept the output of the specific command?

For example: when I send "get-status" command, it returns "Status is 01 02 03". Can I assign this string to the var or text file? Maybe, only "01 02 03" without "Status" text?

```sh
$ps = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$ps.StartInfo.FileName = "plink"
$ps.StartInfo.Arguments = "-telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

[void]$ps.Start() 

$PlinkStreamWriter = $ps.StandardInput

Start-Sleep -m 500
$PlinkStreamWriter.Write("login`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$PlinkStreamWriter.Write("password`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$PlinkStreamWriter.Write("get-status")
Start-Sleep -m 500

Write-Host "Status string: " .....

$PlinkStreamWriter.Write("exit`r")
$PlinkStreamWriter.Close();
if (!$ps.HasExited) { $ps.Kill() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when you send

```
$PlinkStreamWriter.Write("get-status")
```

You receive

```
Status is 01 02 03
```

If this is consistent and you want to assign this value to a variable, just define the variable at the beginning of your command:

```
$result =  $PlinkStreamWriter.Write("get-status")
```

Now if you want to remove "Status is" from the value stored in $result:

```
$result = $result -replace "Status is ",""
```

Now $result contains only `"01 02 03"`

You can now update your `write-host` command:

```
Write-Host "Status string: $result"
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this code ($result =  $PlinkStreamWriter.Write("get-status")), I get an empty $result var.

Comment: OK, but then what is it that sends the string `"Status is 01 02 03"`?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "what is it"? I'm not sure, but maybe there should be some command like "$PlinkStreamWriter.Write" for $ps.StandardInput or maybe Output? That captured plink stream can't be assigned to result value. I've tried some different variants. Thanks for your attention. Oh, and maybe you know some other ways to get powershell script working with no new windows and in hidden mode, but with plink telnet or ssh commands execution?

Answer (score 0):

A simple redirect (`>`) is all that is needed. I verified this works for me in PowerShell v5.1.22000.282. Here is my approach for anyone who needs it.

```
$filepath = "$PSScriptRoot"
$PUTTY="$Env:ProgramFiles\PuTTY\plink.exe"

$commands = @"
y
vncserver -geometry 1920x1080
exit"@

#echoes yes onto putty prompt if it exists and spits output to out.txt

echo $commands | & $PUTTY -ssh $IP -l $USER -pw $PW > "$filepath/out.txt"
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but please be wary of your formatting. I've fixed it for you, but be sure to explore the formatting options for code when making future posts.

Answer (score -1):

This may be of use, you can redirect the outputs from error messages and warning messages into standard out. Example:

> Invoke-Expression "cmd /c 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe'$plinkcmd 4>&1 3>&1 2>&1"